# Print a Google Maps API v3 map with polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to print a map I have created with Google Maps API v3.  The map contains a polygon. I am using the pop-up method to try to print it:

```
var gmapPrint = function() {
  var content = window.document.getElementById('map-canvas') // get you map details
  var newWindow = window.open(); // open a new window
  newWindow.document.write(content.innerHTML); // write the map into the new window
  newWindow.print(); // print the new window
}
```

The map prints just fine, but the polygon is missing.  At first, it seemed as though the print dialog was popping up before the polygon was drawn on the map, so I added a setTimeout.  This did not fix the issue.  I have also tried using the static maps API, but the number of points in the boundary of my polygon exceed the maximum URL size, even when encoded.

Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: Can you just create a copy of your page without anything else on it except for the map and the scripts used to create the map? Then just open that page in the new window. If you need to get sneaky you could pass url parameters to the new page to capture things like the current map zoom level or center point and possibly other things as well.

Comment: A potential solution is reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4182). It's not generalised - (a) as written, it will print only the map, not the whole page, (b) you will need to adjust dimensions to suit your map.

Comment: Oh yes, the solution uses jQuery, though the author forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so Beetroot-Beetroot's comment got me on the right track.  I had seen that post earlier and gave it a quick shot without much luck, but now I've got it working.

Here is a snippet to print a google map without the controls visible.

https://gist.github.com/jawsthegame/6801698

Comment: It is worth noting that this does not work in IE 8 or earlier, due to the lack of <canvas> support.  I can't seem to get an alternate fix to work either.  It is very odd since the polygon is just a series of nested <div>s under the main map container. I'm not sure why they don't get copied to the new window.

Comment: Nice! As for alternate fix: can you get a hold of those divs you mention using a jQuery selector at all (starting at root)?  Wondering if they aren't really nested but are stacked using fixed positioning.